# marshall objects into cookie with functionality retained

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, cookies, marshalling

I have session DOM data that is currently serialized (into a string) and stored within a browser's cookie. and then deserialized (string into DOM) on page load.

The problem is the process of DOM creation is noticeably slow.

I am wondering and hoping its possible to 'marshall' the entire DOM, keeping the function of dialog, spinners, buttons and so forth. those belonging to jquery ui.

Here is a simplified example: 
 given an input tag:   `<input id="spinner"/>`

initializing the spinner via, `$('#spinner).spinner()`

Doing that, wraps my lowly input tag into this:

```
<span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
   <input id="spinner" class="ui-spinner-input" aria-valuemin="1" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton" aria-valuenow="14">
   <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

Second, it binds spinner functions/events to the new spinner object, like click and onchange.

I am capable of storing the entire DOM as a string. But the problem is restoring the spinner functionality. I need to initialize spinner.spinner() again. i cannot simply use it as a spinner. but that init wraps ANOTHER bunch of spinner tags around the first spinner tag.

The workaround is something along the lines of:

I want the spinner function binding, but dont want the extra wrapped tags.

Any way of circumventing that, whether dialog, spinner, button and so on.

Comment: Why are you storing the whole element and not just the values?

Comment: See problem: The problem is the process of DOM creation is noticeably slow.

Comment: Well edit the widget to look to see if the DOM elements are created already.

Comment: that means forking the jquery ui source. the jquery designers may have considered this scenerio, but im at a lack for it.

Comment: It means to extend the widget which is not hard to do, I have done it plenty of times with jQuery UI

Comment: ok. that sounds good. care to offer a direction.